# core data - fail set default value for properties of entity

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, xcode4

I'm using XCode 4.4.1 and used the data model inspector to set default values for properties, but it doesn't save these default values.

Also tried to use the -(void)awakeFromInsert method, but also failed!!

For example I tried to set the value of a Boolean property named "answered"
and tried the code below, but found the same problem:

```
-(void)awakeFromInsert {
self.answered = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
}
```

Comment: What is the kind of failures? Please, post here error description.

Comment: No errors!. The problem is that default data aren't set. 
For example, as I mentioned above, I tried to set default value for the Boolean `answered` property, but default value of it isn't set.

Comment: Please, post here code snippet how do you create new instance of managed object.

Comment: I'm using Cocoa Bindings & NSArrayController, So there is actually no code ! :D
I connect its add action to a button and NSArrayController takes care of the whole thing.

the only code I've added is calling the above method in the managed object's class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your NSArrayController is in Entity, not Class, mode, and that you have the managed object context binding set correctly.

Verify that your data model specifies a class for your entity, not just an entity name (use the Data Model Inspector, command-option-3, while viewing your entity).

If you set a breakpoint in your awakeFromInsert and don't hit it, then you have evidence that you've misconfigured something and that you are not actually inserting instances of your custom NSManagedObject subclass.